# Pronunciation of "'ll"

Tags: pronunciation, contractions, future

How do I read the following sentences (especially in conversational speech)?

> The dog'll eat the bones.
>   Tom'll go to school.
>   Anna'll come tomorrow.

I mean the sound of *'ll*.

Comment: That'll depend. No canonical answer exists.

Answer (score 6):

Phonetically, it's /əl/, rhyming approximately with *cupful*.

Comment: ... after a consonant sound, I would add. In *Anna'll*, *Sarah'll*, *Limbaugh'll*, the schwa is dropped. (Or rather, it is added in all other cases, as a kind of external sandhi.)

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 - not in my speech it isn't.  I would definitely pronounce a schwa (albeit a very short one) in _Anna'll_ and the others.  And although I am neither British nor American, I _am_ a native speaker of English.

Comment: @ RegDwight ΒВBẞ8♦ Yes, I, too, would elide /ə/ after a vowel, if, which is just as likely, I didn't pronounce the entire word in such cases: 'Anne will' and so on. ('Anne'll' sounds just a touch anatomical.)

Comment: I (an American) would keep the /ə/ after a vowel. After /ə/ (as in *Anna* or *Sarah*), I don't think I'd use the contraction at all but say *will*.

Comment: In particular it's a "[dark l](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velarized_alveolar_lateral_approximant)" (in those English dialects that have dark l).

Comment: In American English dialects I'm familiar with, postvocalic /l/ is always velarized ("dark"), while prevocalic /l/ is not ("light"). After a consonant, the contraction _-'ll_ is certainly /əl/, but after a final unstressed vowel, there's generally **some** marking of length -- a shortened epenthetic /ə/ or a lengthened final vowel -- to mark the lost syllabicity of the contracted modal. Final high vowels can generate onset diphthongs: _Mary'll_ /'mɛrijəl/, _who'll_ /'huwəl/ or /huəl/ or /hu:l/.

Comment: Just for completeness, let me correct my previous comment. After /ə/, I change /ə/ to /ʌ/ and add /əl/. So *Anna'll* would be /ænʌəl/. When I wrote my previous comment, I was trying to add *'ll* after /ænə/, and my tongue refused to do it. I don't recommend this pronunciation to anybody who doesn't already do it naturally, for two reasons: (a) I suspect it's really hard to learn to do it and (b) I am fairly sure that a large majority of Americans just lengthen the /ə/ and don't make this vowel change (especially the ones for whom /ə/ and /ʌ/ are the same vowel).

Comment: I'm not a phonetician, so I've nothing to add, I'm afraid.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: You mean "Phonemically".

Comment: Yes, I expect so.