# The pronunciation of "'ll" in spoken English

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pronunciation of “'ll”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66335/pronunciation-of-ll)

Trying to understand completely how "*'ll*" should be pronounced in spoken English, I uploaded a part of AJ Hoge lesson. You can listen to it [here](http://kiwi6.com/file/27bknh23mm).

And the question concerns me a lot is: Does AJ exactly tell about the "dark L" and use it (the "dark L") as well in this lesson and especially in the end of one? And should it be pronounced as "/əl/"?

Comment: Are there two plus questions here?

Comment: There're 2 very similar questions.

Comment: Summarizing the discussion in the duplicate question above: After a consonant, it's /əl/. After a vowel, it depends on the dialect. In the U.K., you just add /l/; in the U.S., either it's /əl/ or you lengthen the vowel and add /l/. Since 'l' is dark when it follows a vowel (in dialects with a difference between dark and light 'l'), here you should use the dark 'l'.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it was velarised and therefore a dark [l].

Not just from listening - it is hard to judge without a word-initial clear l from the same speaker to compare with, but because word-final /l/ is usually a dark l.

The pronunciation of 'will' is /wɪl/. There is no schwa.

If you are interested in phonology, you can hear samples of both clear and dark l here:   >   http://www.soundcomparisons.com/

Comment: I believe the question was really about the pronunciation of the contraction *'ll* and not the full word *will*. It would be good if the OP edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Isn't 'And should it be spelled (or pronounced) as "/əl/"?' asking about the pronunciation of 'will'? I took it that it was, but if it isn't no harm done - he can ignore that one line.

Comment: @PeterShor, definitely. I asked about the pronunciation of "'ll" or "/əl/" and would like to know if AJ means "/əl/" in the end of his lesson.

Comment: The so-called “dark l” is occasionally written `[lˠ]` but more commonly  `[ɫ]`.  So *will* is `[wɪɫ]` if stressed.

Comment: @Alex: I think AJ means /əl/. You certainly can't go wrong using /əl/ to pronounce the contraction *'ll* (except maybe if you're trying to speak with a British accent and it follows a vowel, like *Sarah'll* or *the saw'll*; see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66335/pronunciation-of-ll)).

Answer (score 2):

I'm from England and I pronounce it "/əl/"